# Set of rational functions is which category

Tags: real-analysis

Let $R_{nm}$ be the set of all rational functions whose numerators are polynomials of degree less than $n$ and denominators are (nonzero) polynomials of degree less than  $m$. Is $R_{nm}$ first category or second category in $c[a,b]$  endowed with uniform norm.

Comment: Can you determine whether each of your functions has at least one point at which the function is differentiable? (I'm guessing, however, that if this is homework, then you're supposed to do this from scratch, not deduce the result from a big-gun result.)